# Facebook SDK4.0 Login using custom view

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login

I want log in an user inside my app using the new Facebook SDK with a custom view. Here is my `Fragment`'s `onCreateView()`:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_login, container, false);

    LinearLayout facebook = (LinearLayout) mView.findViewById(R.id.facebook_button);
    facebook.setOnClickListener(new FacebookLoginListener());

    LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mContext.mFacebookCallbackManager,
            new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
                    // App code
                    Log.d("RESULTADO", "SUCCESS");
                }

                @Override
                public void onCancel() {
                    // App code
                    Log.d("RESULTADO", "CANCEL");
                }

                @Override
                public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
                    // App code
                    Log.d("RESULTADO", exception.toString());
                }

            });

    return mView;

}

@Override
public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
    mContext = (MainActivity) activity;
    super.onAttach(activity);
}



public class FacebookLoginListener implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(
                LoginFragment.this,
                Arrays.asList("email"));

    }
}
```

And on `MainActivity`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mFacebookCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    mFacebookCallbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

The Facebook Login Activity shows but I'm not getting the callback...
What is the correct way to implement this login?

Comment: See my answer I just posted, please validate it if u find it usefull, the call back is implemented in the whole class which is a fragment, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: try moving all the code in `MainActivity` to your fragment class.
Does your onActivityResult get called?